# How can I create my @Html.TextBoxFor() as read only or disabled

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.textboxfor

I have a view which creates components dynamically in a partial view and in some cases these components need to be read only. I've managed it successfully with other components using the code below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if("@Model.IsUnderReview" == "True") {
        document.getElementById("textbox_" + "@Model.ID").disabled = true;
    }
});
```

However in this case they are created in a loop and there could be any number of them. How do I take the code below and set it as read only?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Configuration.First(c => c.ID == config.ID && c.ProductRow == config.ProductRow).TextboxEntry, new Dictionary<string, object>{
                        {"id", "infoTextbox_" + Model.NumberOfDuplicates + "_" + config.ID},
                        {"configid", (config.ID + Model.NumberOfDuplicates)},
                        {"onchange", "HandleChange($(this))"}})
```

I've tried inserting @readonly = "readonly" but I either got the syntax wrong as it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add it in the htmlAttributes:

```
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Configuration.First(c => c.ID == config.ID && c.ProductRow == config.ProductRow).TextboxEntry, new Dictionary<string, object>{
                    {"id", "infoTextbox_" + Model.NumberOfDuplicates + "_" + config.ID},
                    {"configid", (config.ID + Model.NumberOfDuplicates)},
                    {"onchange", "HandleChange($(this))"}}, new { @disabled = "disabled"})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your answer through up a few Syntax errors but I tweaked it a little and ended up with {"disabled", "true"}}) which worked.

Comment: @user616076 disabled, readonly, required, and checked are all [Boolean attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute) that are always true when present, and implicitly false when omitted. For example, disabled="yeehaw" is no different than disabled="false", both of which actually disable the element. disabled="disabled" (or any value, really) is merely for XML compliance.